# How do sessions track more than one user

Tags: php, session, tracking

Sorry this is probably a beginners question. If I'm using `$_SESSION` variables how does the server track more than one user/reference them e.g. Say John has logged on `$_SESSION['username']="John"` how would system reference Peter and James who have also logged on because you cannot have `$_SESSION['username']="Peter"` and `$_SESSION['username']="James"` as they would over write each other?

I'm probably missing something simple here.

Comment: You could see the session as a server side file per user (so the users can have different data) with the file name stored in a cookie which is specific for the user. That way, each user gets their own session, and their own session variables.

Comment: When you call `session_start()`, a cookie (called PHPSESSID by default, unless you call `session_name()` for a custom one) sets a session id for the user's browser, which is correlated to session data on the server.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. Does it work like that in real life? If it does what would you need to store in the cookie (I assume as little as possible). I guess I need an example.

Comment: Hi Michael so the tracking 'sessions' to 'users' is handled automatically by the system? Thanks

Comment: @user2976086 If you're running on a single server, PHP may very well store the session in a file. The file name (and the cookie content) is automatically generated to match each other, you don't store anything in the cookie yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2976086

$_SESSION is precisely what keeps users apart for the php server. Each time session_start is called, php server creates a new client session(if such is not already started) which usually results in a cookie named PHPSESSID being created in your browser. On server side, the php server creates, let's say, a unique $_SESSION array for each unique session id(stored in the cookie, only one per browser). That is why you can only log in with one user per browser(you can log in with 2 accounts simultaneously to most sites using firefox and chrome for example as a cookie is created for each browser). That is why u can not "overwrite" $_SESSION['username'] with different user unless you log out in that browser window causing session_destroy to be called or remove the cookie containing sessionid for current user.

try reading:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

Comment: Thanks Bartlomiej. So PHP handles PHPSESSID and $_SESSION array automatically in the background.